# Use xmlhttprequest to get php file

Tags: xmlhttprequest

How do I get from a javascript to php using xmlhttprequest()? I just want to call a php script triggered by an event listener.

```
XMLHttpRequest("GET","load.php",true);
```

Doesn't seem to get any of the code to run. Does it have something to do with the php header?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find another example: [w3school example](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_suggest) or [w3school xml dom main page](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp)

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
       document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","xmlhttp_info.txt",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest object</h2>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```